# Packing 5 identical books into 5 identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to pack $5$ identical books into $5$ identical boxes with no
restrictions placed on how many can go in a box?

No restrictions means some boxes can be empty.

Would it be $\binom{9}{5}=126$?

Comment: Does identical boxes mean that different arrangements don't change the count? For instance is (2,2,0,1,0) equivalent to (1,2,0,0,2)?

Answer (score 3):

You can work this out by hand in this small case.  The possibilities are $(5)$, $(4,1)$, $(3,1,1)$, $(3,2)$, $(2,2,1)$, $(2,1,1,1)$, and $(1,1,1,1,1)$: there are seven possibilities in all.

This is the number of *integer partitions* of $5$.

Comment: What if order is of importance?

Comment: Order of the boxes, or order of the books, or both?

Comment: @mjqxxxx are you serious ? His answer was correct, not ?

Comment: Order wasn't the right word. I meant what if the books are distinguishable and boxes are still indistinguishable

Comment: If the books are distinguishable (but the order of books within a box is irrelevant), then you need to look at the number of partitions of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  This is given by the fifth Bell number: $B_5=52$.